# Opening drive properties through vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I want to create a program using V.NET that enables me to open selected drive's properties, (If security tab open, it would be better).

Answer (score 1):

There is no such facility is available yet. you can access basic Drive information using [`DriveInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as like the following:

```
 Dim myDrive As New DriveInfo("d")
```

[image]

Comment: Cant we do it using calling there "dll" file.